# Access IBOutlet from other class (ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, class, nsobject

I've googled around and found some answers but I didn't get any of them to work. I have one NSObject with the class "A" and a second class "B" without an NSObject. In class "A" are my IBOutlets defined and I can't seem to figure out how to access those outlets from class "B"...

I've found answered questions like http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-662717.html But they're confusing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simplified Version of the Code:

```
aClass.h:

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface aClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
}
@end


aClass.m:

#import "aClass.h"

@implementation aClass
// Code doesn't matter
@end


bClass.h:

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface bClass : NSObject {
}
@end


bClass.m:

#import "aClass.h"
#import "bClass.h"

@implementation bClass
    [textField setStringValue: @"foo"];
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

> I have one NSObject with the class
>   "A" and a second class "B" without an
>   NSObject.

It tells me that you don't have your head around the basic concepts.
Read  through Apple's objective-C introduction, and the tutorial projects.

Comment: I am reading http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157

I guess it will come down to the same eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using **NSNotificationCenter**. Here's a thread telling you how to do it: [Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c/2191802#2191802)

Then in the method reacting to the notification, you call a method accessing the Outlet

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        //NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doIt:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
}
- (void) doIt
{
    //testLabel.text = @"muhaha";
}
```

This worked for me, I hope it does so for you as well.

Comment: where do i write this notification method, in Class A or in Class B?